# AngularJs $cookies is not working with expiry time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set cookies with expiry time but when I am getting back it is showing **undefined**.

I set like this,

```
 $cookies.put('accessToken', JSON.stringify(userObj), {expires: expiry});
```

Can anyone suggest how can I get this in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation, `expires` has to be a
`String of the form "Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT" or a Date object indicating the exact date/time this cookie will expire.`. Are you sure `expiry` is a `String` object with the specified format or is a `Date` object?

Comment: I ma using like this
var expiryTime = 60;
  if (expiryTime) {
               var newDate = moment(now).add(60, 'm');
               expiry = newDate.toDate();
           } else { 
               expiry = now;
           }

Comment: Check https://plnkr.co/edit/RRburOZnRHQQgVMu6ksZ?p=preview . I tried it and it works. Chrome shows that the expiry time is properly set.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in the 1.4.0 build of angular using the ngCookies module:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

```
var expireDate = new Date();
  expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);

$cookies.put('someToken','blabla',{
  expires: expireDate 
});
```

Comment: It's working but i need to add only minutes rather than whole day.

Comment: var expiryMin = 2;
        var expireDate = new Date();
           expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes() + expiryMin)
           $cookies.put("ua", cryto, {
           expires: expireDate
        });//set cookie expirty for 2minutes